# How to find rank of number in a stream of numbers?

Tags: c++, algorithm

We are given a infinite stream of numbers

```
Input stream --> 3 4 5 8 19 23 3 4 100 4
```

The rank of any given number will be the count of smaller numbers to its right.

```
Rank of 100 = 1
Rank of right 4 = 0
Rank of middle 4 = 0
Rank of left 4 = 1 (only 3 is smaller than 4)
Rank of 23 = 3 (3,4,4)
Rank of 19 = 3 (3,4,4)
Rank of 8 = 3
```

I feel we can create BST and store rank with that particular node. Do you guys see any other solution?

Comment: Because we care about numbers ot the right, the answer doesnt exist until the sequence ends, so can we assume the sequence is merely long, rather than infinite.
Are you outputting the rank of all inputs, or some particular input, or other?

Comment: Is the input stream adding to the left? so lets say if you get a 2, will the pattern be now 2 3 4 5 8 19 23 3 4 100 4?

Comment: perhaps left/right are bad. Do you mean the count of numbers which are smaller than it and earlier in the stream. (or do you mean later in the stream).

Comment: @Richard: sorry for confusion, your second comment is right

Answer (score 2):

Let us assume (for now) that you are trying to calculate the number of numbers smaller than you, that have preceded you in the file.

Assuming for a moment uniqueness, someone with this output could construct a sorted sequence in linear time (since they would be given a final insertion location). Thus, for a sequence of N numbers, any comparison based method must take O(NlogN) to calculate this output.

Thus, you really cant do better than a self balancing tree structure, which gives a logN guarantee per step.

Basic Algorithm: You read, insert, check location/distance vs start, output, repeat.

This assumes you tree structure gives you a fast/easy distance/location metric. Trees can do this easily enough, its easy bookkeeping, unfortunately the std::map doesn't, so you would need to find/write one.

Assuming the problem is actually the other way around, just store the numbers in a vector, then process them as above, but in reverse order.

Also, because they are numbers, there may be a radix/bucket sort approach that can do better than logN per step, especially if actual range is small.

Comment: ...Assuming for a moment uniqueness, someone with this output could construct a sorted sequence in linear time (since they would be given a final insertion location)..... <<< my answer was going in this direction I wanted to suggest a sorted copy of the stream to compare the new value with.

Comment: yep, thanks, you look at it and think its easy to do at logN per step, so can I either find a O(1) per step method, or find a proof that you cant do better than logN per step. In this case the latter was easy enough.
Reduction to another problem is the fastest way to prove lower bounds.

Comment: I think you can assume that **you are always in the best case** as the list is already sorted everytime  you are adding the new element. Then you have to add the element in a sorted list. That will cost you n steps only because of the search to find the position, so the actual cost should be logN at best

Comment: I meant the best algorithm should have a weight of logN which is the search for the position. I cannot think any o(1) algorithm (I was thinking about ashing but it doesn't really fit)